# Process.detach pid in python

Tags: python, unix

I would like to detach a child, that is, create a thread whose sole purpose is to wait on the child's pid.
How can I achieve this in python 3?

Comment: Do you mean run a child process, *then* create a thread to wait on the child?  Which operating system?

Comment: Yeah, of course I would need to have created that child first. But making children is not the difficult part. What I'm looking for is a shortcut to abandoning them as effortlessly as possible.

Comment: OK, I see you have a UNIX tag.  If all you want to do is abandon your children then you don't have to wait on them at all.  You might want to set your signal mask to ignore SIGHUP.  Depending on the type of UNIX, SIGHUP will kill the child when the parent dies.  The signal mask for ignored signals is inherited, so you only need set that in the parent.  Are you using `subprocess` or `os.fork`?

Comment: I asked about the way the child is being created because you might have to beware of zombies.

Comment: `os.fork`. Not-waited on children are a resource leak--they turn into zombies. I'm afraid of zombies. My program runs in a server loop. That means a lot of potential zombies. Does it not?

Comment: Yes, you would need `os.wait` or `os.waitpid` to avoid zombies.   Alternatively you could set SIGCHLD to SIG_IGN in the parent which will avoid zombies on most systems - assuming you don't need to wait.

Comment: Thanks, man. `import signal;
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
` did the trick. I'm no longer haunted by zombies. If you're interested, put that into an answer and reap credits.